# How to stop a running php process from browser level

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a PHP application that is build on Zend Framework and Mysql.
I have report page that applies Date range, and query the database and returns the output.
If I choose few days, the query runs fast. But if I choose a date range of couple of months, it takes very long time, due to a large data output.

Now my question is, whenever I run a wider date range, and process start to run for a long time, there is no way for me to cancel it.
I can't stop the browser, or reload the browser, even if I close the browser and open new page, apache does not response. in other word, the process forces apache to hang.
The only way to break this is to Kill the process on linux server or restart the apache.

I was wonder what improvement I can do to the code in order to be able to forcefully stop the process any time I want.

How would you develop your code to avoid a lockup like this? What I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: you can't. all your can do on the browser end is hit `<esc>` and close the connection to the server. But unless PHP notices that the connection has been closed (e.g. by trying to do output), it will keep chugging away until it's done, the cpu/time limit hits, or the heat-death of the universe. And if you're using file-based sessions, you've locked yourself out of all session-using pages, because the running script is keeping the session file locked.

Comment: I would like to rephrase my question.

Comment: due to large data or bad database design?

You can make that page ajax. Let user choose few months, and put limit on view (something like data-tables maybe). So you will ask server limited data only which will be faster. But if it's bad database design it will make problem somewhere else too, so if you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can suggest is using a date range function.
On the front end, when the date is selected and submit button is clicked, trigger a function to calculate the difference in number of days.

If it is longer than the desired range don't let the form submit and show the user a message to choose a lower date range.

Also make sure to validate the same on the page where the queries are being executed so even if the user play around with the javascript, the backend will simply ignore the request and wont execute the query.